# Is Spring Cloud Stream 2.0 compatible with Kafka broker 0.10.2?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

[Spring Cloud Stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) specifies that its version 2.0 is using kafka-clients 1.0 and is compatible with Kafka brokers 1.0, 0.11 (not mentioning 0.10.2 and before).

[Kafka](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix) specifies that broker 0.10.2 (and even 0.10.1) is compatible with any versions of the Java clients, presumably including kafka-clients 1.0.

So are there any compatibility issues specifically between spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 2.0 and 0.10.2 brokers?

I'm planning an upgrade from spring-cloud-stream 1.2 + Kafka 0.10.2 to spring-cloud-stream 2.0 + Kafka 1.0 and am trying to understand if I can do it in one go (clients -> 1.0, then brokers -> 1.0), or otherwise what is the no-downtime upgrade path supported by spring-cloud-stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should work ok (I just tested it with the current snapshot).

However, 2.0 uses native kafka headers by default; headers were introduced in Kafka with the 0.11 broker.

You will need to set the producer `headerMode` to `none` or `embeddedHeaders`. (`none` is a synonym for the deprecated `raw` from 1.x).

1.x uses `embeddedHeaders` by default, or `raw` (`none`) if so configured.

So, you would need to do this anyway, if you want a 2.0 producer to create messages for a 1.x consumer, regardless of the broker version.

On the consumer side, 2.0 will detect whether the message has native or embedded headers (or none).

Another caveat is you can't set the binder property `autoAddPartitions` to `true` unless the broker is at least 1.0.0. The provisioner uses the java `AdminClient`. 1.x used the scala client which could grow partitions.

Comment: Good to know that a consumer will look for both kinds of headers, that was another one of my concerns